# Automatically fix filename cases in C++ codebase?

Tags: c++, automation

I am porting a C++ codebase which was developed on a Windows platform to Linux/GCC. It seems that the author didn't care for the case of filenames, so he used

```
#include "somefile.h"
```

instead of

```
#include "SomeFile.h"
```

to include the file which is actually called "SomeFile.h". I was wondering if there is any tool out there to automatically fix these includes? The files are all in one directory, so it would be easy for the tool to find the correct names.

Comment: I'd probably just cobble together a quick and dirty perl script to do this sort of thing, cos it would take less time than searching for a tool that did something more principled.

Comment: Any decent editor really. Notepad++ would be able to do it.

Comment: Every IDE has find/replace for multiple files in a dir. What do you use?

Comment: Maybe just rename all the files in the project to lowercase?

Comment: I assume that the questioner wants something better than using an editor's Replace In Files dialog for a few dozen/hundred filenames.

Comment: sorry if that wasn't clear from the question: I was talking about many filenames, so Find&Replace was what I tried first but noticed it's too much. And actually even renaming to lowercase wouldn't work because some includes were ok (aside from Coding Guidelines...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Before doing anything note that I'm assuming you either have copies of the files off ot the side or preferably that you have a baseline version in source control should you need to roll back for any reason.

You should be able to do this with `sed`: Something like `sed -i 's/somefile\.h/SomeFile.H/I' *.[Ch]`

This means take a case-insensitive `somefile` (trailing `/I`) and do an in-place (same file) replacement (`-i`) with the other text, `SomeFile.H`.

You can even do it in a loop (totally untested):

```
for file in *.[Ch]
do
    sed -i "s/$file/$file/I" *.[Ch]
done
```

I should note that although I don't believe this applies to you, Solaris `sed` doesn't support `-i` and you'd have to install GNU sed or redirect to a file and rename.

Comment: in case someone else is going to use this: a little caution! This script replaced "CMatrix H;" to "Cmatrix.h" because I have a file called matrix.h and I guess the dot stands for any character? But everything else was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive my, I'm away from my linux environment right now so I can't test this myself, but I can tell you what utilities you would need to use to do it.

1. Open a terminal and use `cd` to navigate to the correct directory.

   `cd ~/project`
2. Get a list of all of the .h files you need.  You should be able to accomplish this with the shell's wildcard expansion without any effort.

   `ls include/*.h libs/include/*.h`
3. Get a list of all of the files in the entire project (.c, .cpp, .h, .whatever), anything that can #include "header.h".  Again, wildcard expansion.

   `ls include/*.h libs/include/*.h *.cpp libs/*.cpp`
4. Iterate over each file in the project with a for loop

   ```
   for f in ... # wildcard file list
   do
       echo "Looking in $f"
   done
   ```
5. Iterate over each header file with a for loop

   ```
   for h in ... # wildcard header list
   do
       echo "Looking for $h"
   done
   ```
6. For each header in each project file, use `sed` to search for `#include "headerfilename.h"`, and replace with `#include "HeaderFileName.h"` or whatever the correct case is.

   **Warning: Untested and probably dangerous:**  This stuff is a place to start and should be thoroughly tested before use.

   ```
   h_escaped=$(echo $h | sed -e 's/\([[\/.*]\|\]\)/\\&/g') # escapes characters in file name
   argument="(^\s*\#include\s*\")$h_escaped(\"\s*\$)" # I think this is right
   sed -i -e "s/$argument/\$1$h\$2/gip"`
   ```

   Yes, I know it looks awful.

Things to consider:

- Rather than going straight to running this on your production codebase, test it thoroughly first.
- `sed` can eat files like a VCR can eat tapes.
- Make a backup.
- Make another backup.
- This is an O(N^2) operation involving hard disk access, and if your project is large it will run slowly.  If your project is not gigantic, don't bother, but if it is, consider doing something to pipe `sed`'s output to other `sed`s.
- Your search should be case insensitive: it should match #include, #INCLUDE, #iNcLuDe, and any combination of case present in the existing header filename, as well as any amount of whitespace between the include and the header.  Bonus points if you preserve whitespace.

Comment: the regex I used, `(^\s*\#include\s*\")$h_escaped(\"\s*\$)`, should match pretty much any include statement that will sensibly exist, including ones with whitespace in wonky places and weird capitalization.  The replacement should rebuild the statement exactly as it was originally written, and should change only the filename within the quotes, and will only change the case of the filename, nothing else.  I'm assuming your library includes (using <>) are cased correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Notepad++ to do a 'Find in Files' and replace.

From toolbar:
Search - Find in Files. 
Then complete the 'Find what' and 'Replace with'.